# Latest comments from each category?

Tags: categories, comments

On the "home"-page I'm trying to display the most recently commented-on post for each category.

I managed to display the most recently published post for each category, but if an older post from each category gets a comments, that post should be bumped to the top of the list with that latest comment displayed.

Here's the code I tried:

```
<?php $cat_args=array(
  'child_of'=>1,
  'exclude'=> 12,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
   );
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
      'showposts' => 1,
      'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
      if ($posts) {
        echo '<div class="pffcat"><h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name.'</a></h2> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post); ?>


            <?php $recent_reviews = get_comments('post_id='.$post->ID.'&status=approve&number=1');?>

             <?php
                  foreach($recent_reviews as $recent_review) {
                    $comment_url = get_permalink($recent_review->comment_post_ID).'#reviews';
                    $comment_info = get_comment_meta($recent_review->comment_ID, 'comment_info', true);
                    $comment_rating = get_comment_avg_rating($comment_info);
                ?>

                <div id="post" class="post">
                  <div class="entry-summary">
                    <p><strong>Restaurant: <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent_review->comment_post_ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($recent_review->comment_post_ID); ?></a></strong></p>
                    <p><?php echo get_limit_content(strip_tags($recent_review->comment_content), 150); ?></p>
                    <p><a href="<?php echo $comment_url; ?>" class="more-link">read review</a></p>
                  </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
                </div><!-- #post-## -->
                <div class="searchbox-r-home">
                  <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/star-m-<?php echo $comment_rating; ?>.png" />
                  <span><?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($recent_review->comment_date)); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php } // foreach($recent_reviews as $recent_review) { ?>
          <?php
        } 
        echo '</div><!--end box -->';// foreach($posts
      } // if ($posts
    } // foreach($categories
?>
```

Comment: do you want to show the recent comments from each category or the latest commented post from each category? like sorted by comments?

Comment: To be more specific, the setup is
Neighbourhoods as categories,
Restaurants as posts,
Reviews as comments.

On homepage I list the latest review, just one, for a restaurant (displaying just the name of the restaurant as post title not the whole post and the followed by the review) for every Neighbourhood (category)

The problem is that every query I've tried displays the latest review  for  he *latest added* restaurant (post) to the homepage. I need the list to update with reviews added for restaurants published at a previous date. Basically a sort by latest comment in the output of the query.

Comment: Please make an edit to your question and show the code you already tried.

Comment: Added the code I tried.